# Proposition 12.15 in Lee's topological manifolds: Is the Hausdorff assumption missing?

Tags: general-topology

In proposition 12.15 of his "Introduction to topological manifolds" Lee proves a statement about the action of a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ on a connected and locally path-connected topological group $G.$

In the first line of his prove he writes:
"Because $\Gamma$ is discrete, there is a nbhd $V$ of $1$ such that $V\cap \Gamma=\{1\}.$"

For me, however, this looks like it uses the Hausdorff property (or at least I don't see from what else this should follow). Am I missing something (maybe some part of a definition or some simple statement)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need $G$ to be Hausdorff. That $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup means it is a discrete space in the subspace topology. Hence the singleton $\{1\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $1$ in $\Gamma$. And by definition of the subspace topology that means there is an open $V \subset G$ such that $V \cap \Gamma = \{1\}$.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I was somehow thinking that discrete just means finite.